# How can the volatile keyword affect a static const array?

Tags: c, volatile

This is a mindblower and anyone who can answer it deserves massive recognition! It is actually a couple of connected questions that I am asking to get better understanding.

The drivers for the STM32 ARM Cortex platform have the following code in them:

```
static __I uint8_t APBAHBPrescTable[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

`__I` is defined as:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
  #define     __I     volatile                /*!< defines 'read only'   permissions      */
#else
  #define     __I     volatile const          /*!< defines 'read only'   permissions      */
#endif
```

My program is a C program compiled with a GCC cross-compiler. Thus the array declaration is effectively:

```
static volatile const uint8_t APBAHBPrescTable[16] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

Question 1:

Given that this is a constant array, why use the `volatile` keywork here?

My understanding is that the `volatile` keyword means that the contents of the array can change, but the `const` means that they cannot.

The only use of this array in the code is three uses like this:

```
tmp = RCC->CFGR & CFGR_PPRE1_Set_Mask;
tmp = tmp >> 8;
presc = APBAHBPrescTable[tmp];
```

When I dump the values of `tmp` and `presc` I find that `tmp` has a value of 4 and `presc` has a value of 0. Index 4 is the 5th element of the array which has a value of 1. There are no other accesses or uses of this value...At all...Anywhere.

Question 2:

How might the value changed between it being declared?

When I dump the array I see it is filled with zeroes.

It happens reliably...until I remove the `__I` from the array declaration. This makes me think it is not a buffer overflow. Other than that I cannot think of anything.

I would think that the `volatile` keyword was there for a reason, except that I also saw code like the following in an interrupt handler where, as far as I understand, the `volatile` keyword is redundant:

```
volatile uint32_t status = USART2->SR;
```

This variable is local to the function and as such can never be changed by code elsewhere.

======== EXTRA DETAIL ========

Here is the annotated disassembly of the relevant piece of code. The value at (RCC_GetClocksFreq+128) is zero, but appears at some point to have had the address of the prescaler lookup table copied into it:

```
0x000001d0 <+56>:    ldr     r1, [pc, #68]   ; (0x218 <RCC_GetClocksFreq+128>)
       ...
   tmp = RCC->CFGR & CFGR_PPRE1_Set_Mask;
   tmp = tmp >> 8;
0x000001de <+70>:    ldr     r4, [r2, #4]
0x000001e0 <+72>:    ubfx    r4, r4, #8, #3
   presc = APBAHBPrescTable[tmp];
0x000001e4 <+76>:    ldrb    r4, [r1, r4]
   RCC_Clocks->PCLK1_Frequency = RCC_Clocks->HCLK_Frequency >> presc;
0x000001e6 <+78>:    lsr.w   r4, r3, r4
0x000001ea <+82>:    str     r4, [r0, #8]
```

Here is the same, but with the `volatile const` macro replaced with `const`:

```
0x000001d0 <+56>:    ldr     r4, [pc, #68]   ; (0x218 <RCC_GetClocksFreq+128>)
       ...
   tmp = RCC->CFGR & CFGR_PPRE1_Set_Mask;
   tmp = tmp >> 8;
0x000001de <+70>:    ldr     r1, [r2, #4]
0x000001e0 <+72>:    ubfx    r1, r1, #8, #3
   presc = APBAHBPrescTable[tmp];
0x000001e4 <+76>:    ldrb    r1, [r4, r1]
   RCC_Clocks->PCLK1_Frequency = RCC_Clocks->HCLK_Frequency >> presc;
0x000001e6 <+78>:    lsr.w   r1, r3, r1
0x000001ea <+82>:    str     r1, [r0, #8]
```

They are essentially identical. Yet somehow removing the volatile keyword solves the problem!

Comment: It might be worth noting that the code in question is supplied by the Keil cross compiler people and has been observed to work correctly with this board for many years - but using the Keil compiler not the GCC compiler.

Comment: There's lots of programs out there that use `volatile` as a magic talisman, without understanding what it actually does.  I suspect this is one of those programs.

Comment: `__I` = UB. You ought to rename the symbol.

Comment: Easy explanation. It signals that the const variable (from your code point of view) might be changed by something else and has to be read everytime you access it. The good example are read only hardware registers which are writable for the underlying hardware

Comment: @Bathsheba: UB? What is that?

Comment: Undefined behaviour.

Comment: @PeterJ: I know that. But in this case it is a lookup table which shouldn't change as otherwise it will break everything. It is converting a bit field value (as defined by the reference manual) into a prescaler value. I.e. 4 means divide the clock frequency by 2. This is defined in the reference manual and hence the behaviour should never change and so the lookup array should never change. Thus the volatile keyword is just wrong. But even beyond that, how can the values change when nothing can change them. There are no references ar all to map this address to hardware.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Wow that was quick! :) In what way does `__I` cause undefined behaviour, and how will renaming it help? Surely the effect is the same whether the name is `__I` or `ReadOnlyVar`? Or am I misundestanding you?

Comment: maybe overuse of volatile - a very common programmer illness

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, thanks for all the comments and answers that led me to this answer.

When the variable is defined without the "volatile" keyword it is put into a readonly section of the binary file.

When the variable is defined with the "volatile" keyword it is put in the same section of the binary file as all other variables.

I have recently found 3 buffer overruns and I am sure there are others. A lot of the code is not very well written. It is likely that when the "volatile" keyword is specified the variable is so placed in memory as to make it vulnerable to a buffer overrun. There is no reason at all for this particular variable to be marked as volatile so the simple fix is to remove that keyword. The proper fix is to do that and also track down the buffer overrun and fix it.

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding is that the volatile keyword means that the contents
>   of the array can change, but the const means that they cannot.

`volatile` means the program must read the value from memory every time it is used. `const` means the *program* may not change the value, but the environment (or "OS") may.

This explains the behavior you observed: Without `volatile`, the compiler assumes it is OK to read the value once and use it multiple times.

Comment: In general, other things might also change the program, not just the OS. In this particular case I don’t know of any, but you can have a `volatile const` changed by another thread of the same program, another program with shared memory, and probably a few other things I’m not thinking of.

Comment: Yes there are other things that may change the value, the hardware for example, but another thread may not change a `const` value, `volatile` makes no difference here.

Comment: I counted the hardware changing the value as part of the OS changing it, in this case. Another thread can change a value *your thread* thinks is `const` if pointers are involved, or in the C++ side if references are. Not if it was declared `const` from the very beginning like this, but that’s why I said that I wasn’t sure of any other sources in this particular case.

Comment: Ah yes, now I get what you mean, and I agree. (I had the `const` array from the question in mind, but there could also be a `const` pointer to non-`const` data)

Comment: As I said in the question, there are no other references to the array. ANYWHERE. Hence nothing else should be changing it. It is not mapped to shared memory. It is not mapped to a register. Or if it is, this is not done by any code, either in the same file or elsewhere in the codebase. How can the hardware change the contents of this array?

Comment: A memory-mapped register was what I had in mind. `USART2->SR` for example sounds like a status register. The array however does not look like this. I can only guess, maybe the linker does something special with it? You could try to create a minimal program that only reads this to rule out that it is changed by an error like a buffer overflow.

Comment: @Alain, your explanation of volatile is clear but adds nothing to what I already knew. There is a big jump in logic from that definition to "This explains the behaviour you observed". This is a static integer array in a code file. When compiled it becomes a section of memory in the program image. When executed the program image may or may not get copied to RAM. What could cause the hardware to change this memory? What possible bug (I doubt a buffer overflow as already explained) could cause this.

Comment: @Alain We got comment crossover :P It is a lot of work to produce a minimalist program so I just added another similar array. However I could not reproduce the problem with this new array.

Comment: Did you ask this question because something doesn't work as it should, or because you wanted to know why that `volatile` is there? If it's the latter I think your experiment with removing it shows why it's there. It makes the program read the changed value. I really don't know how it is changed, sorry, I can only say there must be some "magic" injected somewhere. (Or, a bug).

Comment: @Alain I really appreciate your insights here. If the linker does something special with it, that must be defined somewhere - there must be somewhere that tells the linker to do something special with it, but I cannot find that. Secondly, the array is just a lookup table, telling the program what the prescaler for the clock is for a given registry value. It should never change. Hence why I think the volatile should not be there in the first place, and secondly why even if it is there I think it should not change.

Comment: I changed the name of the array and got the same effect, so it cannot be something the linker is doing!

Answer (score 1):

The `volatile const` construct may be used by a Real Time Clock to publish the current time:

```
volatile const struct tm TheTimeNow;
```

- The clock cannot changed by your program, so it should be `const`.
- The clock ticks permanently and magically behind your and the compiler's back, so better use `volatile` to force the compiler to fetch always the current time instead of old timestamps.

The RTC might have an own section in the address space, where it exhibits the current time.

Comment: How would the RTC know to change this variable or where to find it? Where is it defined that this is the variable name to change and not something else?

Comment: @AlastairG: Basically there are two ways: [Memory Mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) where at given addresses in the address space some hardware only behave like RAM. But in reality it reflects the status of port pins or other. Often microcontrollers having this. The other way is that some software changes the value behind your back. A OS may provide a fixed  memory location where you can read available memory, disk space etc. The exact address of those objects are usually fixed and well-known, so the compiler / linker can resolve them.

Comment: Memory mapped IO I understand, but it isn't the case here. It cannot be software changes (barring buffer overflow or something) as it is static and so cannot be addressed outside the file it is declared in. Also it is const. That array is only ever readf within the file it is declared in.

Comment: Oops, I think I made a wrong turn and went off the track. I just realized that you should be able to add `volatile` to **every** variable without breaking the program logic. Maybe the performance becomes poor, but this is not the issue here. But when you remove `volatile` your compiler sees only `const` and assumes no alteration of the data and starts optimizing. And exactly this feature may hide a memory corruption in APBAHBPrescTable[] outside our scope!!

Comment: I suspected memory corruption. I analysed the disassembly, and the only difference between the version with volatile and the version without was which section of the program the storage was placed in. I couldn't see where any buffer overrun could come from. I looked at the storage adjacent to the array that seems to be getting corrupted and there was no buffer or suchlike that I could see.

Comment: You wrote "When I dump the array I see it is filled with zeroes." So you **do** have a memory corruption. You can get such corruption without harming other areas with code like `int Array[10]; Array[1000]=0;`. And such memory overwrite may land by accident on your PrescalerTable. Use your debugger and set a data breakpoint on PrescalerTable to find when it changes value. If this is not available spread extensively code like `if  (APBAHBPrescTable[4]!=1) printf("Houston, we have a problem! At line %d", __LINE__);` among your code. This will allow you to narrow the overwrite.